# How can I detect the frameworks and/or libraries used in any Source Code Repository/Directory programatically?

Tags: github, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

Suppose I have a source code directory, I want to run a script that would scan the code in the directory and return the languages, frameworks and libraries used in it. I've tried [github/linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist), its a great tool which even Github uses to detect the programming languages used in a source code, however I am not able go beyond that and detect the framework exactly.

I even tried tools like [it-depends](https://github.com/trailofbits/it-depends), to fetch the dependencies but, its getting messed up.

Could someone help me out to figure out how I can do this stuff, with an existing tool or if have to make one such tool how should I approach it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, in the general case, impossible. The [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) precludes any program from being able to compute, in finite time, what other programs may or may not do - including what dependencies it requires to run. Sure, you can make it work for *some* inputs - but never for all.

So you have to compromise:

- which **languages** do you need to support? `it-depends` does not try to support Java, for example. Different languages have different ways of calling in dependencies from their source-code. For example, if working with C, you will want to look at `#include`s.
- which **build-chains** to you need to support? parsing a standard `Makefile` for `C` is very different from, say, looking into a Maven `pom.xml` for `Java`. Additionally, build-chains can perform arbitrary computation -- and again, due to the halting problem, your dependency-detection program will not be able to "statically" figure out intended behavior. It is entirely possible to link against one library or another one (or none at all) depending on what is detected to exist. What should you output in this case?. For programs that have no documented build process, *you simply cannot know their dependencies*. Often, the build-process is human-documented but not machine-readable...
- what do you consider a **library/framework**? long-lived libraries can evolve through many different versions, and the fact that one version is required and not another may not be explicit in the source-code. If a code-base depends on behavior found in only a specific, now superseded, version of a library, and no explicit mention of that version is found -- your dependency-detection program will have no way to know about it (unless you code in library-version-specific detection; which is doable, but on a case-by-case basis, and requires deep knowledge of differences between versions).

Therefore the answer to your question is that... [it depends](https://github.com/trailofbits/it-depends#can-it-depends-do-it-it-depends-) (they go into a fair amount of detail regarding limitations). For the specific case of Java + Maven, which is not covered by `it-depends`, you can use Maven itself, via [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html). *Choose a subset of the problem instead of trying to solve it all at once*.